# Strapi : What is the Content and API migration strategy

Tags: strapi

Strapi is a powerful tool, but I am unable to find any documentation/instructions which explain about the best practices/strategy to migrate contents from one environment to another, for example Dev to staging to production ?

If you got a lot of content and recreate all the content on each environment is not viable.

Please guide, how to move API and DB (mongo) stuff.

If there is only manual workaround for now, we should document it so that can be used for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now there is no other way than manually import/export your database:

[Github issue: Import / export data](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/744)

Comment: and what about APIs

Comment: There is a good plugin, but you need to build it yourself and it breaks in `heroku`'s deployment.

Comment: @SalahAdDin can you place the link please?

Comment: https://github.com/lazurey/strapi-plugin-content-export-import
this one, look on comments if you want to deploy it to Heroku.